# Sort a 2-dimensional array diagonally with a column of values in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

How do I sort values by a column, let's say I have a 2-dimensional array like this:
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 1, 2, 2]
and I want it sorted in descending order of the bottom row of numbers, like:
[E, D, C, B, G, H, A, F]
[8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
sorry if my English is bad :(

This is my try to count the time that the alphabet appear

```
s = str(input()).upper()
z = list(set(s))
z.sort()
if z[0]==' ':
    z.remove(z[0])
kitu = [z, [' ']* (len(z))]
dem = []
for i in range(len(z)):
    kitu[1][i] = s.count(z[i])
    dem.append(s.count(z[i]))
```

I'm using Python and quiet new to it, thank you for ur help <3

Comment: Why the expected result have less values?

Comment: my bad my bad, sorry

Comment: You have List of Lists not an array in the row, column sense. It would be better to convert to a Numpy array and then sorting is very simple.

Comment: Why do you have `z = list(set(s))` in your attempted solution? Are you expecting all the elements in the first list to be unique? And are you aware that converting it to a `set` to and then back to a `list` change the original order? `list(set(a)) != a`

Comment: @user19077881 Why would it be better to convert to numpy for such a small data set? And how would it be easier for a beginner to understand numpy API than plain Pyrrhon?

Comment: @zvone I'm assuming this is a larger or generic problem with a simple example; otherwise why bother with sorting by code. I also consider it useful to guide away from thinking of Python Lists as rows and columns. Basic Numpy is not that difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your expected result have lesser values as @guy have mentioned but I think you might be expecting this -

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'] # row1
b= [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 1, 2, 2] # row2
d = dict(zip(a,b)) # create dictionary
#sort the dictionary {key:value} in descending order by it's value element
sorted_dict = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda elem: elem[1], reverse=True))
# Convert the dict into 2D array
arr = [[k,v]for k,v in sorted_dict.items()]
print(arr)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you remove the `dict(...)` part at the end, and extract the 0th element of the tuple in `d.items()` after sorting, then the OP gets the letter list directly: `[x[0] for x in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda elem: elem[1], reverse=True)]` → `['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'G', 'H', 'A', 'F']`. Also, making a dict won't work if any of the elements in `a` are repeated. However, OP has `z = list(set(s))` in their attempted solution, which may or may not be what they actually want.

Comment: yeah, that's right!